# Getting Custom Field value in WP_Query

Tags: customization, wp-query

i am trying to display first post of 3 categs on my index page. so for that i wrote a little function as follows:

```
function excateg($categ) {
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=$categ&showposts=1");
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
$imageurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-img', true);
endwhile; 
}?>
```

Afterwards the Html for showing the image and title and image.. but i am unable to get the custom field as above in $imageurl to get a value..

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `$post` global variable if you want to access its ID property:

```
function excateg($categ) {
  global $post;
  $recent = new WP_Query("cat=$categ&showposts=1");
  while($recent->have_posts()){
    $recent->the_post();
    $imageurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-img', true);
  }
}
```

Use it after the_post() because that function will set up that variable.

Alternatively you can use the `$recent->post` property instead of `$post->ID`...